# CMIS .NET Open Source Server Side Library

Tags: .net, cmis

Is anyone aware of a CMIS .NET Open Source Server Side Library?

Basically I am looking for the server side of [DotCMIS](http://chemistry.apache.org/dotnet/dotcmis.html)
Or the .NET side of this [OpenCMIS Server Framework](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/guide.html)
I get I would need to write all implementations
Basically I want the abstract base classes that need to be implemented
I have a .NET document management application I want to add CMIS to
Not sure it matters but I am not interested in browser binding
Only care about AtomPub Binding Web Services Binding

Found NCMIS on CodePlex but it has not been active since 2010

Answer (score 1):

FlexNet is a .Net project on Github which has a server-side CMIS implementation:

[image: FlexNet Github Repo]

**References**

- [FlexNet Source: CMIS Service](https://github.com/maxpavlov/FlexNet/tree/master/Source/SenseNet/Services/Cmis)
- [An open-source Document Management solution for the University of Thessaloniki (pdf)](http://www.eunis.org/eunis2015/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2015/06/Parallel-2-Track-3-Paper-67-An-open-source-document-management-solution.pdf)
- [Differences between Community and Enterprise editions - version 6.5.4 - Sense/Net Wiki](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Differences_between_Community_and_Enterprise_editions_-_version_6.5.4)